# Is there a word or phrase to describe children becoming better versions of their parents?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word in any language that describes the thought of a child becoming better than their parents in what they do. For example a child who is eventually going to take over the family business and when they do, do it, they do it better than their parents did.

Thanks so much for anyone who can help me out with this.

Comment: Wow. +1 for this. I have a phrase in my mother tongue. Can't think of any in English though!

Comment: It may help inspire more answers if you add an example of how you would like to use this word in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase that isn't exactly about a parent/child relationship, but is related:

> The student has become the master.

It's used when a pupil learns so much that he or she exceeds the skill of their teacher.

---

Specifically for a child, one could use something along the lines of "she is more successful than her mother" or "he surpassed his father's legacy".